# Bootstrap justified nav items with caret

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My problem is the carets are sliding under the texts in justified bootstrap menu. Like this: http://www.bootply.com/VWo8Oc7mVz

Is there any automated method to have the carets next to title of menu item in justified mode? I have only 1 solution now, i define the widths for every menu item with css, but it is not an effective solution.

**Edit:** in my development site I already tried reducing the horizontal padding of the anchor elements. It didnt work, there are too much menu item. I refreshed the bootply link also with this.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the anchor tag under nav has certain padding around by bootstrap. You can reduce left and right padding and giving enough space to caret by adding

```
 .nav>li>a{
    padding : 10px 5px;
    }
```

Demo : http://www.bootply.com/0GpdHsNVB4

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried reducing the padding on left and right. It didnt work on my working site, like this: http://www.bootply.com/VWo8Oc7mVz

Answer (score 0):

As you can find in [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) "Pills with dropdowns":

```
<li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
  Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  ...
</ul>
</li>
```